# Create Edge list for (900+) nodes (in R)

Tags: r, large-data, network-analysis, edge-list

I have a problem creating an edge list of 406351 edges (possible combinations of two nodes out of 902 unique nodes). The nodes correspond to doctors, and the edges correspond to the number of patients two nodes share in a period of time (one year).

I have medical claims data, with one observation being one visit of one patient to a particular doctor.

So far, what worked for me was to: First, table the doctors against the patient's id, obtaining the number of visits each patient had with each doctor. After that, I took the list of unique doctors' id, and create an edge list with all the possible 2 elements combinations. Finally, I "filled up" the edge list with a for loop that looks into each combination of columns(doctors) in the table, and counts how many particular patients had visits>0 for both columns(doctors).

This works, but my problem is that the loop is too slow and I would like to know if there is a faster way of doing this.

Here an example of my approach so far:

```
    #DATA
    case_number<-c("123","3456","5433","5678","9874","8566")
    doctor_id<-c("333","444","555","333","666","555")
    patient_id<-c("1","2","2","2","1","1")
    DATA<-data.frame(case_number,doctor_id,patient_id)

    #Table doc vs patients
    table<- as.data.table(as.data.frame.matrix(table(DATA$patient_id, 
    DATA$doctor_id)))

    #Create edge list
    Drs<-unique(DATA$doctor_id)
    edge_list<-as.data.table(t(combn(as.vector(unique(Drs)), 2)))

    #'fill up' edge list
    for (z in colnames(table)) {
    for (y in colnames(table)) {
        edge_list<-edge_list[(V1==z & V2==y) | (V2==z & V1==y),
                     Weight:=nrow(table[table[[z]]>0 & table[[y]]>0])]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I realized that with some matrix algebra I could create an adjacency matrix and then use the network package to create the edge list. Comment if you need the code!